# Convert pandas column of string of list of dictionaries into separate rows

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have following data frame:

```
col1                             col2                           col3    
usr_entry   {"key_1":"i89","key_2":"desktop","key_3":100},   2023-08-01   
            {"key_1":"i254","key_2":"mobile","key_3":"67"}
```

I would like to explode col2 into separate rows and from dictionaries' keys create columns, obtaining result:

```
   col1     key_1   key_2   key_3     col3
usr_entry   i89   desktop   100   2023-08-01
usr_entry   i254  mobile    67    2023-08-01
```

I'm trying to achieve that by making col2 a list of dictionaries and use `json.loads()` to make columns out of it, but col2 is pandas Series and it can't be converted using `json.loads()`. The example I gave is just one row in bigger dataFrame, so I would like to achieve what I want for the whole dataset.

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now it's not obvious what kind of data you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming, you have json string like this in the dataframe (note: `col2` is string):

Initial `df`:

```
        col1                                                                                            col2        col3
0  usr_entry  [{"key_1":"i89","key_2":"desktop","key_3":100},{"key_1":"i254","key_2":"mobile","key_3":"67"}]  2023-08-01
```

---

Then you can do:

```py
import json

df["col2"] = df["col2"].apply(json.loads)

df = df.explode("col2")
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df.pop("col2").to_list(), index=df.index)], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        col1        col3 key_1    key_2 key_3
0  usr_entry  2023-08-01   i89  desktop   100
0  usr_entry  2023-08-01  i254   mobile    67
```

---

EDIT: If you missing `[ ]` around the string you can do:

```py
import json

df["col2"] = df["col2"].apply(lambda x: json.loads("[" + x + "]"))

df = df.explode("col2")
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df.pop("col2").to_list(), index=df.index)], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        col1        col3 key_1    key_2 key_3
0  usr_entry  2023-08-01   i89  desktop   100
0  usr_entry  2023-08-01  i254   mobile    67
```

Comment: my initial col2 is: '{"key_1":"i89","key_2":"desktop","key_3":100},{"key_1":"i254","key_2":"mobile","key_3":"67"}', and when I try to convert to list it generates list of one long string

Comment: when I'm trying your method it gives me JSONDecodeError: Extra data

Comment: @Lucas You can try the example in my edit.